# Track a count through a wpdb statement

Tags: sql, wordpress

#### What I'm trying to accomplish?

Getting the count of something, more specifically when the user presses a button on a specific post. I need an SQL statement to keep 
track of that count(don't worry I'm going to get more specific).

#### Table structure

This is a normal WordPress table structure where I'm focusing on the following tables:

- `wp_posts` --> `ID`, `post_title`, `guid`
- `wp_term_relationships`

| object_id  | term_taxonomy_id   |  term_order  |
|-------------|--------------------------|----------------|
|-----6------|------------1-------------|---------0-----|
|-----22----|-------------2------------|----------0-----|
(table formating, I tried)

- `wp_term_taxonomy`

| term_taxonomy_id  |  term_id           | taxonomy-----------| description | parent | count |
|--------------------------|-----------|------------------------|----------------|----------|-------|
|-------------1----------- |-----1----|---------0-------------|----------------|  -----0---|---10--|
|------2-------------------|-----2----|  *button action's tax* |--------------             |-----0---|----4---|

#### What I noticed

I'm just getting started with wordpress, and I'm unfamiliar with the table structure but I noticed that the buttons action in my
plugin created an iteration in `wp_term_relationships --> term_taxonomy_id` so I built an SQL statement around that where I stored 
the post Id as `$post` and compared it to the `object_id` in the `wp_term_relationship` table. Got the specific term_taxonomy_id for
that respective post ID then I subtracted it by one since that `term_taxonomy_id` is initialized as one when a post is created.

#### Thought I solved it this way

```
global $wpdb;  
$ID = get_the_ID();
$count = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_taxonomy_id FROM wp_term_relationships WHERE object_id = '".$ID."' ORDER BY term_taxonomy_id DESC LIMIT 1");
$the_count = $count - 1;
echo $the_count;
```

#### Problems/Questions

I was told over and over again that this will not work if something changes in the database. I just don't know what that something
is, and what kind of statement I need to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with the taxonomy tables.  You'll break stuff unless you're very careful. Plus, that's not where you want to store this information.

You want to keep and update a hit count as an *attribute* of a post.  Attributes go in the `wp_postmeta` table, not the taxonomy subsystem.

You don't have to write a query to do this. You can simply use the [`get_post_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/) and [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) functions.

Something like this should do the trick for you.

```
$hit_count_key = '_hit_count';
$hit_count_val = get_post_meta( $post_id, $hit_count_key, true );
if ( $hit_count_val === false ) $hit_count_val = 1;
else $hit_count_val++;
update_post_meta( $post_id, $hit_count_key, $hit_count_value);
```

(I haven't had a chance to debug this code. But you get the idea.)

The leading underscore on the key means that the attribute isn't displayed in the post edit screen. If you want the attribute displayed, don't use the underscore.

Comment: Let me play around with this. I like this solution. Will likely mark answered soon.

Answer (score 0):

you are confused, if i`m not wrong, you want to create a counter (How many people are clicking in X post, wright?).

1. In table wp_term_taxonomy, the 'count' row, it's not the times a user has click on the post.those numbers are the number of terms asociate to a Taxonomy.
2. If you want a counter there is a [fast way](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-views-counter/) or a 'Hard way'.
3. Hard way: create your own plugin and use [wp_options to save your data](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-the-wordpress-options-table--cms-21119)

Comment: the count I was getting was from subtracting 1 from `term_taxonomy_id` not from the count column specifically. Unfortunately, this is for a plugin needs to be accomplished through this means, however I don't understand why using wp_options is necessary there is no relationship to the tables I'm looking for.